# How do I check whether user enters an integer between 2 numbers?

Tags: java, input, integer

I want the user to input integers between 80 and 120 with no alphabets and other symbols. Here are my codes:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {     

public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//checking for integer input
    while (!in.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and 120.");
        in.nextInt();
        int userInput = in.nextInt();

//checking if it's within desired range
        while (userInput<80 || userInput>120)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and 120.");
            in.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, I'm facing an error. Is there a solution to this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Array.main(Array.java:15)
```

Thank you! :)

EDIT: Thank you Tom, got the solution, but would like to try without "do"

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userInput;
    do {
    System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and 120.");
    while (!in.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("That's not an integer!");
        in.next();
        }
        userInput = in.nextInt();
} while (userInput<81 || userInput >121);

System.out.println("Thank you, you have entered: " + userInput);
}
}
```

Comment: Sure there is! `catch` the `java.util.InputMismatchException` and deal with it appropriately. Out of interest, why are you skipping over an input?

Comment: @Bathsheba hi there, i would like to do it without use of catch, as I'm revising my school work and this is just the first few topics (haven't learnt catch exception at this point)

Comment: Change the condition to while (in.hasNextInt())

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is wrong. You check something like "as long as there is no integer available from the input: read an integer". That is gonna fail

Also: You are calling `nextInt` twice. Don't do that. Remove the first call:

```
System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and 120.");
in.nextInt(); //REMOVE THIS LINE
int userInput = in.nextInt();
```

You are checking once if an int is available using `hasNextInt`, but then you read a value twice!

Comment: I've tried, still getting the same error.

Comment: yep, I'm tried removing it and I still got the same error D:

Comment: `while (!in.hasNextInt())` Maybe your problem is here.

Comment: I think your problem is while (!in.hasNextInt()) because you are explicitly telling it to check for ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean continueOuter = true;

    while (continueOuter)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and 120.");
            String InputVal = in.next();

        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(InputVal);
              //checking if it's within desired range
             if(FirstInput>80 && FirstInput<120)
            {
               //no need to continue got the output
                continueOuter = false;
            }else{
                  System.out.println("Please enter integers between 80 and  120."); //need to continue didnt got the exact output
                 continueOuter = true;      
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
        //not an int    
       System.out.println(InputVal);
       continueOuter = true;
        } 
}
```

in this code i have created a boolean to check whether the program wants to continue or not. if the user has entered a valid value the program will stop 
however you can change that as you wish. and you dont need two while loops i have changed the inner while loop to a if loop take a look at my code

Comment: `continue = false`? Good luck with that in Java.

Comment: i was referring to continueouter  that was a mistake .

Comment: @priyamal hi there, what if user enters a character? i head character refers to number or something.

Comment: edited the code. Codes  within catch block will get executed if not an int . if the input is a int, code within try block will be executed.

Comment: you mean `String` ?? :D:D sorry i wasnt using the ide , really sorry about that appreciate that you pointed it out.